# *ngFor is displaying empty list while fetching data from API

Tags: angular, ionic3

While fetching data from my API it displays an empty list.
But I made modifications in the code, like in **home.html**, I wrote the following code:

```
<h1>{{data[i].name}}</h1>
```

It retrieves only the 2nd list item from the array and `i` is giving output as **0 1 2** whereas my database has more than 10 records. Loop is not working.
So how to resolve this...

This is my code::

```
//AuthServiceProvider
private url: string="http://localhost/php_rest_myblog/api/post/read.php"
getData(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .do((res:Response)=>console.log(res))
      .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
  }

//service.pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'service', pure: false
})
export class ServicePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args:any[]=null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }
}


//home.ts
export class HomePage {
  dataList = [];

  getData(){
    this.authservice.getData()
    .subscribe(
      data=>{ this.dataList=data; });
  }
}


//home.html
  <ion-list>
    <h3>List is here</h3>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let data of (dataList |service); let i = index">
       <h2>{{i+1}}</h2>
       <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>
       <img src="{{data.image}}"> 
       </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: add this to your html to diagnose the issue `{{dataList | json}}`

Comment: in your home.ts, change your subscribe to this `response=>{ this.dataList=response.data; });`

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. It has solved the issue.